# How to test PRNG?

Tags: testing, random, prng

Lately I implemented a MersenneTwister for 64-bit `integer` (or `long`). Is there a guide or examples of how to test PRNG so that I may know whether or not my implementation is good-enough solution. I'm specially interested into how to verify if my implementation has good enough uniform distribution.

The more specifically this is tied to MersenneTwister the better.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You do not need to test the Mersenne Twister **algorithm** -- that's been done over and over by people who really know what they're doing -- you only have to test whether you've correctly **implemented** the algorithm.

You can go to the [Mersenne Twister web site](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt.html) and grab their [test output](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/mt19937-64.out.txt). If you produce the same sequence of outputs that they do, you've probably implemented the algorithm correctly.

Note that the MT site has a link specifically for [64 bit machines](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/emt64.html) and different test outputs for 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: There is just one tiny problem with that. C uses unsigned 64-bit integer. To my knowledge Java doesn't really have unsigned `long`. Is it safe to assume that if all non-negative `long` generated this way are same and have the same ordering then both implementations are identical?

Answer (score 8):

The standard battery of tests for a PRNG is the [Diehard Tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests).

Comment: I don't know enough to know which is better, but it seems good to use both.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest approach (If it's truely generic MT) would be to compared it with a known-good MT library with the same seed.

Comment: That would be it, but there are two problems. I know of only one MT-64 library but it doesn't have all the functions I need to test (it only offers nextInt, while I have implemented nextDouble, nextIntFromRange, etc.). IIRC there is a difference between MT-64 and MT generated seeds so I can't use the second library (which has all the missing functionality) to check it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Aloha!

As someone else said - use the known answer test vectors for the algorithms. If you meet the test vectors you can be reasonably sure that your generator works.

If you really want to test the generator. Use the DIEHARD tests++ as implemented by the Dieharder tool:

http://www.phy.duke.edu/~rgb/General/dieharder.php